# Common element in Java infinite streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have three infinite Java `IntStream` objects. I want to find the smallest element that is present in all three of them.

```
    IntStream a = IntStream.iterate(286, i->i+1).map(i -> (Integer)i*(i+1)/2);
    IntStream b = IntStream.iterate(166, i->i+1).map(i -> (Integer)i*(3*i-1)/2);
    IntStream c = IntStream.iterate(144, i->i+1).map(i -> i*(2*i-1));
```

I can always employ a brute force solution (without streams) which involves iterating in nested loops, but I was wondering if we can do it more efficiently with streams?

Comment: Define *"next element that is common"*. Do you mean e.g. if 3rd element of each stream are equal to each other they are "common"? Or could 5th element from `a`, 2nd element from `b`, and 7th element from `c`, be considered a "common element" if they are equal?

Comment: @Andreas I should have said that the next element that is present in all of them. Edited.

Comment: So if elements is index 5, 2, 7 (respectively) are equal, that is the value you're looking for? What if 7, 2, 5 or 7, 5, 2 or ... are also common? Which one do you want to see?

Comment: @Andreas I want to see the smallest number present in all three of them.

Comment: There is no research effort, but otherwise the question is clean and useful. I don't think it deserves a down vote.

Comment: @sank "I want to see the smallest number present in all three of them." - the streams are infinite so finding the smallest might be quite complex. I mean definitely more difficult than just finding first occurrence.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak The functions are monotonically increasing. Hence the first occurrence will be the smallest.

Comment: @sank Are you sure that it has an answer? I am hitting integer overflow.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I was trying to solve this Euler project problem this way.  https://projecteuler.net/problem=45

Comment: @sank Your seeds in the iterate methods are wrong. You should start with all of them being 0. Then the first tuple that you find should be 40755 and the question is asking for the next tuple after that.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak The tuple (285, 165, 143) corresponds to 40755. I want the next tuple. Hence my seeds are 286, 166 and 144 respectively.

Comment: It is not a good way to find it... Enumerate all T(n) for n≥286 and then solve both equations T(n) = p(3p-1)/2 and T(n) = p(2p-1)

Comment: @sank yes, you are right about the seeds, my mistake :) although it's helpful to start with 0 (or 2) to verify that your program finds the solution 40755.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate all 3 in parallel, advancing the one with the lowest value, checking if all 3 are equal.

You code will not find an answer for next value after `40755`, because the next value is `1_533_776_805`, which has intermediate value (before division by 2) higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`2_147_483_647`).

So, here is one way to use your streams, after changing them to `long` and guarding against overflow.

```
LongStream a = LongStream.iterate(286, i->i+1).map(i -> Math.multiplyExact(i, i+1)/2);
LongStream b = LongStream.iterate(166, i->i+1).map(i -> Math.multiplyExact(i, 3*i-1)/2);
LongStream c = LongStream.iterate(144, i->i+1).map(i -> Math.multiplyExact(i, 2*i-1));

OfLong aIter = a.iterator();
OfLong bIter = b.iterator();
OfLong cIter = c.iterator();

long aVal = aIter.nextLong();
long bVal = bIter.nextLong();
long cVal = cIter.nextLong();
while (aVal != bVal || bVal != cVal) {
    long min = Math.min(Math.min(aVal, bVal), cVal);
    if (aVal == min)
        aVal = aIter.nextLong();
    if (bVal == min)
        bVal = bIter.nextLong();
    if (cVal == min)
        cVal = cIter.nextLong();
}
System.out.println(aVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

These functions are always increasing. So the code should stop when the magic equal triplet is found.

The thing to code is:

a) when a stream's current value is below any other, it can iterate next for itself.

b) when it meets the same candidate value, it waits for the 3rd stream to take a decision.

c) when it has a higher value than the all others, it changes the candidate and waits for both others.

Reference juggling.

There may not be a solution too (at least in short time).

Notice that stream c can only produce even numbers (when seeded with even). There might be some optimization there to skip a and b faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything smart possible with stream API. The main reason is that you can't really go over one stream until some condition is met - instead, you look at current 3 elements and pick the next element from one of the streams before comparing the elements again.

The most efficient (and might be also the cleanest) solution is to use iterators and keep calling `next()` method on the right streams until the answer is found.

To start with, you can focus on two streams only and find their first common value:

```
while (elementA != elementB) {
    if (elementA < elementB) {
        elementA = iteratorA.next();
    } else {
        elementB = iteratorB.next();
    }
}
```

Then you need to do make third stream catch up with these two:

```
while (elementC < elementA) {
    elementC = iteratorC.next();
}
```

At this point there are two options:

- either `elementC == elementA` in which case you have the answer
- or `elementC > elementA` in which case you can go to next value on all three streams and start over

One thing to remember is the max value of integer. Because you have `i^2`, this means that it will overflow for `i` about 46k, so you need to change streams of ints to streams of longs (the answer is about 1.5 billion - and that's after division by 2 in these functions).

Since you are doing exercises for practice, I don't think it's right to give you the full working code, but let me know if you still struggle with it ;)